# Discord.py, awnser for an random choice

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I would like my software to be able to respond to choices made by people in the discord text rooms.

For that, I created 2 following functions :

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
   result = re.search(r'Hi, (.*) ou (.*)\?', message.content)
   if result:
       await message.channel.send(f"Hum, {message.author.display_name}, i choose {random.choice([result.group(1).strip(), result.group(2).strip()])} !")
   await bot.process_commands(message)
```

and

```
@bot.event
    async def on_message(message):
       result = re.search(r'Hi, (.*)\, (.*) ou (.*)\?', message.content)
       if result:
           await message.channel.send(f"Hum, {message.author.display_name}, i choose {random.choice([result.group(1).strip(), result.group(2).strip(), result.group(3).strip()])} !")
       await bot.process_commands(message)
```

except that the software gets lost between these two functions and does not respond to them

I tried this to merge them into one :

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    nbchoix = re.search(r'(.*)', message.content)
    if nbchoix == 2:
        result = re.search(r'Hi, (.*) ou (.*)\?', message.content)
        if result:
            await message.channel.send(f"Hum, {message.author.display_name}, i choose {random.choice([result.group(1).strip(), result.group(2).strip()])} !")
    if nbchoix == 3:
        result = re.search(r'Hi, (.*)\, (.*) ou (.*)\?', message.content)
        if result:
            await message.channel.send(f"Hum, {message.author.display_name}, I choose {random.choice([result.group(1).strip(), result.group(2).strip(), result.group(3).strip()])} !")
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

But it's did'nt work... Please someone help ? i'm a begginer on python

Comment: The reason your first code doesn't work is because you can't have multiple functions with the same name, so you can't have to on_message events.
For your second code attempt... In what way doesn't it work? Is there any error code?

Comment: Ok i see... ! For the second quetion, i haven't error code but just it's didn't work

Comment: `nbchoix = re.search(r'(.*)', message.content)` is going to match any characters, it's not just going to match the placeholder for choices you have in your other regexes.

Comment: Ok i see, thanks for your reply